# Confusion over the various equations of energy in basic special relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, covariance

I have a fairly longstanding confusion over several different equations involving energy in special relativity and I struggle to see how they relate to each other.

1. $E=mc^2$
2. $E=\gamma mc^2$
3. $E=mc^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$
4. $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$
5. $P^0=E/c^2$ (the $0-$component of the four momentum)

Could someone explain in which situation each of them is used and if any of them are equivalent? I am comfortable with four-vectors and tensor equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statement (1) Is the energy of a particle at rest by virtue of its mass. In such a frame, $\gamma = 1$, so in fact (1) is just a special case of (2).

Statement (2) is the relativistic energy of a massive particle in any frame, as a function of its speed $v$.

Statement (3) is only valid in the case $v \ll c$. If you expand statement (2) as a Taylor series in small $v/c$ you will obtain (3).

Statements (4) and (5) are related to the 4-momentum of a massive particle:

$$p = (E/c^2, \vec{p}) = (\gamma m,\vec{p}).$$

If you form the contraction $p_\mu p^\mu$ for a particle at rest ($\gamma = 1$) you will obtain (4). (5) is simply a definition.

Comment: How do we relate (2) and the square root of (4)?

Comment: If you substitute $p = \gamma m v^2$ and take the square root of both sides, after a bit of algebra you'll see they are the same.

Comment: Why $\gamma mv^2$ not $\gamma mv$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo; it should be $\gamma m v$

Comment: Ah I see thank you, I will see if I can get the right result

Answer (score 2):

I guess 4. is the most general formula. It works both for massive/massless particles. For massive particles you can use $p=\gamma mv=mc\beta\gamma$. In that case 4. is equal to 2.:
\begin{align}
E^2&=m^2c^4+m^2c^4\beta^2\gamma^2\\
&=m^2c^4\left(1+\beta^2\gamma^2\right)\\
&=m^2c^4\gamma^2\\
\implies E&=\gamma mc^2
\end{align}
Even though 4. is more general formula 2. is often derived first.

When a particle is at rest you famously get formula 1.

You can Taylor expand $\gamma\approx 1+\frac {\beta^2} 2$ in formula 2. to get formula 3. This holds when $v\ll c$.

Finally 5. is just a convenient way to express energy and momentum as a four vector. You have to proof once that the energy and momentum transform like a four vector and then you can conveniently use tensor notation. This notation is useful because you know how tensors transform and it is easy to construct Lorentz-invariant quantities like $p^\mu p_\mu$

Comment: Thank you, this answer was also very helpful, the derivation between 4 and 2 was something I've never seen before and made things a lot clearer.